# cscript - Invalid procedure call or argument when running a vbs file

Tags: windows-server-2003, nagios, vbscript

I've been trying to use [check_time.vbs](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Uncategorized/Windows-time-check-against-NTPD-%28check_time-2Evbs%29/details) to check the Windows time.

Here's the script: http://pastebin.com/NfUrCAqU

The help message could be display:

```
C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts>cscript //NoLogo check_time.vbs /?
check_time.vbs V1.01
Usage: cscript /NoLogo check_time.vbs serverlist warn crit [biggest]

Options:
 serverlist (required): one or more server names, coma-separated
 warn  (required): warning offset in seconds, can be partial
 crit  (required): critical offset in seconds, can be partial
 biggest (optional): if multiple servers, else use default least offset

Example:
cscript /NoLogo check_time.vbs myserver1,myserver2 0.4 5 biggest
```

But I get the following error when running:

```
C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts>cscript //NoLogo check_time.vbs 0.asia.pool.ntp.org 20 50
C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\check_time.vbs(53, 1) Microsoft VBScript run
time error: Invalid procedure call or argument
```

The screenshot:

[image]

Manually execute `w32tm` still works fine:

[image]

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: This should really be asked on SO.

Comment: Definitely more of an SO question IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is the `/nowarn` argument:

```
w32tm /monitor /nowarn /computers:0.asia.pool.ntp.org
The following arguments were unexpected: /nowarn
Exiting with error 0x80070057
```

Remove it from the script, and now it works:

```
cscript //NoLogo check_time.vbs 0.uk.pool.ntp.org 20 50
NTP OK: Offset -2.4262131 secs|'offset'=-2.4262131s;20;50;
```

Comment: Don't know why my `w32tm` version doesn't supply the `/nowarn` argument (`w32tm /? | findstr nowarn` returns nothing). I'm using Windows Server 2003, Version [5.2.3790], Service Pack 2.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the (53,1) indicates that the error is on line 53. At this point it is expecting an array of regexp matches with at least one item (index 0) and one sub-match (i.e. the object in position 0 in the array has an array property called SubMatches with at least one item in it.

It is not checking to make sure this structure is present and correct before trying to use it.

My assumption is that the regexp call is failing to find anything to match, presumably because the input string is not in the expected format. You could output the content of `strOutput` before that line to see what it contains - it could be a date/time representation in a different localized form than the regexp is designed for. You could also output the content of `input` after each call to `objProc.StdOut.ReadLine` - this would show you if the call to `w32tm.exe` returned a useful error message that is being skipped over by the script which is just looking for the value returned when all is well and ignoring the possibility of different output.